# Why *p operand needed in while statement in this program?

Tags: c, pointers

In this program below

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>

#define MAX_LEN 100

void reverse_name(char *name);

int main(void)
{
    char name[MAX_LEN+1];
    printf("Enter a first and last name: ");

    fgets(name, sizeof(name), stdin); 
    reverse_name(name);

    return 0;
}

void reverse_name(char *name)
{
    char *p = name, initial;

    while (*p && *p == ' ')
        p++;
    initial = *p++;

    while (*p && *p++ != ' ');

    while (*p && *p != '\n')
        putchar(*p++);
    printf(", %c.", initial);
}
```

the function `reverse_name` has three `while` statements and all have `*p` operator. Instead, modifying those to

```
    while (*p == ' ')
        p++;
    initial = *p++;

    while (*p++ != ' ');

    while (*p != '\n')
        putchar(*p++);
```

the program still puts the same output like

```
Enter a first and last name: Lloyd Fosdick
Fosdick, L.
```

Why is the operand `*p` needed in `while`?

Comment: Do you understand how the original `reverse_name` works?

Comment: The original function probably wanted to ensure that you stopped when it encountered `nil`.

Comment: You might try with a string that does not contain a space or `\n`. Whatch the difference in a debugger.

Comment: In the first one `while (*p && *p == ' ')` it isn't necessary, in the others with a negative test it is. They used a nail and a screw.

Answer (score 0):

`while(*p)` is a sloppy but common way of writing the 100% equivalent `while(*p != '\0')`. That is, a check against the null terminator. This check is absolutely necessary to ensure that we aren't reading out of bounds of the string.

When we have something like `while (*p && ...` then the `&&` operator guarantees that the null terminator check is done before the right operand is executed.

Another option would have been to pass the string length to the function. Then we'd know how long the string is and wouldn't need to check for the null terminator all the time.

As a side note, writing something like `*p && *p++` is horrible practice. It happens to be well-defined in this specific case, but in general it's very dangerous to mix `++` operators with other operators in the same expression. Why whoever wrote this code chose to change coding style inconsistently from while loop to while loop, I have no idea.